# List<string> into List<int>

Tags: c#

I want to convert a `List<string>` into `List<int>`

here is my `List<string>` :

```
string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("versengok.txt");
List<string> stringname = new List<string>(text.Split(','));
```

Comment: can u be more specific?

Comment: So, I read from one text into list<string> and this is in text string. After this a converted this string in list<string> with commas separators. Now I want to convert this List<string> into List<int>.

Comment: if I write this line, that will make a mistake: List<int> versengok = stringname.ConvertAll(s => Int32.Parse(s));- Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: int is only numeric , how can u add string as int , its not possible as i tried much, u can get the index value of tht list .

Answer (score 4):

List has a [`ConvertAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73fe8cwf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

```
var intList = stringname.ConvertAll(int.Parse);
```

Comment: +1 This is a neat solution.  Did not know about the ConvertAll() method.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the strings in the list contain valid integers:

```
var integers = stringname.Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToList();
```

If the strings aren't valid integers but something else, you'll have to elaborate on what exactly you expect. Although generally speaking, in a 1-for-1 conversion, the conversion logic (whatever that may be) should most likely go in the lambda inside `Select()`.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
List<int> intList = stringname.Select(x=>Convert.ToInt32(x)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use any library function, loop through all items in StringList and convert them to IntegerList:

```
List<int> Convert(List<string> stringList)
{
    List<int> intList = new List<int>();  

    foreach (String str in stringList) 
    {  
        intList.Add(int.Parse(str));  
    }
    return intList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
string text = "1,2,3,4,5,5";
List<int> intArr = new List<int>();
text.Split(',').ToList().ForEach(item => 
{
 int x = Convert.ToInt32(item);
 intArr.Add(x == null ? 0 : x);
});
```